# How to use Google Performance Tool when run app with argument .so file

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

Now, I have a problem with Google perftools. My function in app called .so file is a argument, and I run start.sh with content:

```
CPUPROFILE=out.pprof PROFILEFREQUENCY=10000000 <Process binary> <Process configure>
```

Result is received from it:

> out.pprof with size = 3,8KB

. And during 2-6 hours, this file isn't changed. I reviewed it and it didn't show .so file that I transmitted.

Please help me find out a reason for this.
Thanks a lot